# Can my Worktable forget its recipes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forestry

I have a [Forestry Worktable](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=crafting:worktable) that I have used before, but now I'm using it for other things. It currently has its entire memory for previous recipes full. I'm only using it at this time to make one particular item, so is there a way to clear the memory of the other items it remembers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to *clear* the memory, but you don't have to worry about it being too full to learn new recipes.

The Worktable remembers the last 8 recipes it was used to manufacture. So if you were to create an item not in its memory, it would keep the last 7 recipes and drop the 8th.

If you want to start creating other items, but don't want to lose a recipe being stored in the Worktable's memory, you can right-click the recipe to "lock" it and prevent it from being bumped off by newer items.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, unfortunately I already knew all this except if you can\can't clear the memory. I'm OCD and simply wanted it clear of the stuff I wasn't planning on making anymore. O well.